# Get the response "ContentType" in a nodejs http request

Tags: node.js

I want to donwload a file via http and check the "ContentType" response header. My Download looks like this:

```
var fileUrl = "<url>";
var request = https.get(fileUrl, function (res) {
res.on('data', function (data) {
    //...
});
res.on('error', function (error) {
    //...;
});
```

I get the data, but is there any way to acces the content type resonse header?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `res` variable is an instance of [`http.IncomingMessage`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage), which has a [`headers`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_headers) property that contains the headers:

```
var request = https.get(fileUrl, function (res) {
  var contentType = res.headers['content-type'];
  ...
});
```

Comment: you can also bind `request.once('response', (res) =>{res.headers;})` to get it.

Comment: @mh-cbon passing a callback to `https.get()` is basically the same (it's a one-time listener for the `response` event).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only mime-type, be aware that Content-Type header can include other information such as charset or boundary.

[image: Boundary]

[image: Charset inside content type header]

Use parser such as [content-type-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/content-type-parser) instead of reading header directly.

```
const contentTypeParser = require("content-type-parser");
const contentType = contentTypeParser(req.headers['content-type']);
const mimeType = contentType.type+'/'+contentType.subtype;
```